# ASP.NET WebApi POST not recognizing form-urlencoded int array

Tags: javascript, c#, file, post, asp.net-web-api

So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11006138/5543032) post gives an answer to how to send a post for downloading a file using forms. But my API endpoint isn't recognizing the form data.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DownloadPdfs([FromBody] IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    if (ids == null || ids.Count() < 1)
    {
        return BadRequest("No ids supplied.");
    }
    ...
```

'ids' always has a count of 0.

---

Here's the JS code:

```
function downloadFile(ids) {    
  var win = 'w' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000000);
  window.open('', win, 'width=250, height=100');
  var f = $('<form></form>')
      .attr({ target: win, method: 'post', action: 'api/pdfs' })
      .appendTo(document.body);
  _.each(ids, function (id) {
      $('<input></input>')
          .attr({ type: 'hidden', name: 'ids', value: id })
          .appendTo(f);
  });
  f[0].submit();
  f.remove();
}
```

Initially, I just had it the same as the other linked answer which was just one input appended to the form, in which I set the value to 'ids'. I tried this next, but that still didn't work.

Does anyone know how to adapt this to still use post data to provide my ids, which are needed to create and supply the downloaded file? Or is there a better way to do this?

I've tried doing it just using Ajax, which returns the file content in the responseText, but I can't make use of it in there and I can't get the browser to open it.

**Edit 1**

- I also just tried setting the value to this:

      `value: '{ids: [' + ids.toString() + ']}'`

  That didn't work.

**Edit 2**

- Just tried changing the endpoint parameter to this: 

      `([FromBody] int[] ids)` 

  ...to no avail.

Comment: and where is your js code?

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni Sorry, should have put that in off the bat.

Comment: @dferenc I actually just modified the title. I realized that was not very clear about the actual problem. But apparently yes, I can't get the data to make it into the endpoint.

Comment: @DanielEcker Thanks for clarifying! Removing my other comments now.

Comment: Using a network tool (dev tools on your browser, fiddler), can you show the exact body of the API request?

Comment: @pep I mean...it shows the form data being sent in the body. I switched it to just take one id instead and the body of the request had this: id=1763. It's not json...does it need to be?

Comment: I would have thought the C# web api could handle form encoded content...

Comment: Right, I know it should just show form data - I asked for the exact body of the array request because it's important, even though it should be straighforward. "I switched it to take just one id" did you also change the "name" property of the input to "id"?  Because the body you posted has a param named *id* and not *ids* as shown in your code here, which is confusing.

Comment: @pep Yes, sorry, I switched everything to be consistent with just having one id named appropriately for each part. So you want the body when I send the array of ids?

Comment: Here's the body of the array request:
ids=3825&ids=3826&ids=3827&ids=3828

Comment: I think this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324529/mvc-web-api-post-an-array-of-integers-via-x-www-form-encoded

Comment: Quirks of webapi model binding, IMO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162113/discussion-between-goonpontoon-and-p-e-p).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Web API post an array of integers via x-www-form-encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324529/mvc-web-api-post-an-array-of-integers-via-x-www-form-encoded)